What are some of the books that cover the theme of chess preparation using Artificial Intelligence & chess engines
Came across the book Game Changer by Matthew Sadler and Natasha Regan on AlphaZero’s discoveries and opportunities using AI in chess. What are the other books on the same theme?

The Silicon Road to Chess Improvement by Matthew Sadler. This is an amazing book and well worth some intensive study. See also the book-related YouTube channel.

Possibly a bit off-topic to the narrowed question, but certainly relevant in a broader sense: "Think like a Machine". What we can learn from machine-style play.
